# SQL - not exists query with millions of records

Tags: sql, sas, not-exists

I'm trying to use the following SQL query (in SAS) to find any records from `pool1` that do not exist in `pool2`. `Pool1` has 11,000,000 records, `pool2` has 700,000. This is where I run into an issue. I let the query run for 16 hours and it was nowhere near finishing. Is there a more efficient way (in SQL or SAS) to achieve what I need to do?

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE ALL AS
SELECT A.ID
FROM POOL1 A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT B.ID
                  FROM POOL2 B
                  WHERE B.ID = A.ID);
QUIT;
```

Comment: So the query should return 10,300,000 records?

Comment: @Matt . . . No.  These would be going into the table `all`.

Comment: How about duplicate table A, then delete from table A records that exist in table B.

Comment: In a perfect (SQL) world, a.id and b.id would be (primary) keys. SAS does not have keys, so you'l have to emulate them by adding (unique?) indexes on both a.id and b.id.

Comment: No indexes needed.  See @Steve Matthews answer below.

Answer (score 4):

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE ALL AS
SELECT A.ID
    FROM
        POOL1 A
    WHERE A.ID NOT IN (SELECT B.ID
                        FROM
                            POOL2 B)
                        ;
```

The above change should return the same result set but take considerably less time to run as you are not trying to join POOL2 back to POOL1 but simply excluding results which exist in POOL2.

As stated in another answer, an INDEX may help but if the ID fields are the primary keys it is likely they are already subject to in INDEX.

Comment: This is the best way I have found to tackle this in SAS.  A toy problem with 100x less records takes 14 seconds to run via the `NOT EXISTS` statement with the sub query join.  This method take 0.03 seconds!  No indexes were created in the toy.

Comment: Also of note, a full toy problem with 11,000,000 and 700,000 records takes 5 seconds via this method with no indexes.

Comment: Wow that's kind of counter-intuitive.  I wonder if it's using a hash lookup internally to achieve those kinds of speeds...

Comment: @RobertPenridge, I would guess so.  Most of the time is probably sorting/indexing/hashing (whatever) the smaller table results from the inner query.  This would take longer if you reversed the tables.

Comment: Without any indexs on the ID field you can see the detail of what it's actually doing; it will perform a table scan to extract the ID's, then a sort ascending on the extracted field, then performs an Anti Semi Join to weed out the results to want to exclude, exploiting the fact that it's already sorted them.  Add indexs and all you see is a clustered index scan.  It performs very well and scales beautifully.

Comment: Huh. I'm really surprised that the query optimizer did figure that out itself.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is fine.  In most databases, `not exists` is the best way (or one of the best ways) to express this logic.

However, you need an index for performance:

```
create index idx_pool2_id on pool2(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this in SAS, so why not use a data step?

```
data all;
  merge pool1(in = a) pool2(in = b keep = ID);
  by ID;
  if a and not(b);
run;
```

This requires that both datasets are either sorted or indexed by ID. If you have multiple records per ID in B then I would suggest deduplicating first via

```
proc sort data = pool2 out = temp nodupkey;
  by id;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE ALL AS
SELECT A.ID
  FROM POOL1 A
       LEFT JOIN POOL2 B ON B.ID = A.ID
 WHERE B.ID IS NULL
```