# SAS SQL - Two tables (A and B) where the only shared field is the key - want everything in A that is NOT in B

Tags: sql, join, sas, proc-sql

I have two tables where the fields are different except for a shared key.  I need to only keep the records with keys that are in A and NOT in B.  I don't want records that are only in B or records that are in both A and B (so to exclude anything in the inner join).

I see SAS SQL references to "EXCEPT" but it seems that can only be used if all fields are shared across the two tables since a key is not used.  Is there another way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - not exists query with millions of records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430157/sql-not-exists-query-with-millions-of-records)

Comment: @OP - if you have a specific need (such as for particular performance), you would need to describe that in more detail in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use SQL?

```
data want ;
  merge A (in=in1) B(keep=id in=in2);
  by id;
  if in1 and not in2 ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
proc sql;
    select a.*
    from a
    where not exists (select 1 from b where a.key = b.key);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `exists` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   b
                   WHERE  a.id = b.id)
```

Comment: SAS's implementation of `NOT EXISTS` seems to be somewhat slow, for whatever reason.  It's probably that most SAS programmers don't use indexes.

Answer (score 0):

One more approach with `except` is to get all id's (or the key column) in A that are not in B. Then use those `id`s to get all records from A.

```
select a.*
from a
inner join (select id from a except select id from B) t
on a.id = t.id
```